# calculate (substract) two numerary lists stored within $var1 and $var2. storing each result to its own new variable. (shell: /bin/ash; busybox)

Tags: calculation, ash

I have to lists stored in $var1 (variable) and $var2 (=const.). The values in both $var's are stored space seperated.
I'm limited to /bin/sh and I want avoid to store files in /tmp because the data for $var1 is changing every sedond. While the script is refreshing every 3 seconds. Running on nand flash device.

For $var1 we have e. g.:

```
80000
70000
60000
50000
40000
30000
```

For $var2 we have e. g.:

```
6000
5000
4000
3000
2000
1000
```

Now I want to make a "simple" substraction for each line: $var1(line1) - $var2(line1); e. g. 80000-1234=74000 and so on for each line. I want to store each in its own new variable e. g. $delata{i}.

So the end result look like:

```
delta_new_1=74000
delta_new_2=65000
delta_new_3=56000
delta_new_4=47000
delta_new_5=38000
delta_new_6=29000
```

What did I try:

```
$deltas=$(using grep reading from a file) # static (more or less correction factors)
$data=$(using grep reading some sensors) # variable

var1=$(for i in $deltas; do echo "$i"; done)
var2=$(for i in $data; do cat "$i" 2>/dev/null || echo 0; done)

c=0

while read -r i <&3 && read -r j <&4 ; do

    DELTA=$((j-i))
    eval delta_new_$c="$DELTA"; c=$((c+1));

done 3<"$var2" 4<"$var1"
```

I'm struggling already to create a linefeed separated list using sed while I'm not even sure if I would need it. I've tried varA=$(sed -i "s/ /\n/g" "$var1") resp. varB=$(sed -i "s/ /\n/g" "$var2"). It did nothing

Without converting (sed lines) I end up with:

```
-ash: can't open 74000
65000
56000
47000
38000
29000: no such file
```

The values are substracted. But e. g. echo $delate_new_1 is empty (ofc due to errors before).

Most examples I can find are utilize bash arrays. They are not available on ash. A lot of other tools are not available also. So basically I'm limited to ash.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Thx at those for at least reading it. :)
The calculation line is adjusted to my needs and could be written probably better.

```
c=1
set -- $var1
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
        eval old"$c"="$1"
        c=$((c+1))
        shift
    done

c=1
set -- $var2
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
        eval delta"$c"="$1"
        c=$((c+1))
        shift
    done

if [ -n "$old1" ] && [ -n "$delta1" ]; then delta_new_1=$(($old1 - $delta1)); else unset $old1 && unset $delta1; fi
if [ -n "$old2" ] && [ -n "$delta2" ]; then delta_new_2=$(($old2 - $delta2)); else unset $old2 && unset $delta2; fi
if [ -n "$old3" ] && [ -n "$delta3" ]; then delta_new_3=$(($old3 - $delta3)); else unset $old3 && unset $delta3; fi
if [ -n "$old4" ] && [ -n "$delta4" ]; then delta_new_4=$(($old4 - $delta4)); else unset $old4 && unset $delta4; fi
if [ -n "$old5" ] && [ -n "$delta5" ]; then delta_new_5=$(($old5 - $delta5)); else unset $old5 && unset $delta5; fi
if [ -n "$old6" ] && [ -n "$delta6" ]; then delta_new_6=$(($old6 - $delta6)); else unset $old6 && unset $delta6; fi
if [ -n "$old7" ] && [ -n "$delta7" ]; then delta_new_7=$(($old7 - $delta7)); else unset $old7 && unset $delta7; fi
if [ -n "$old8" ] && [ -n "$delta8" ]; then delta_new_8=$(($old8 - $delta8)); else unset $old8 && unset $delta8; fi
if [ -n "$old9" ] && [ -n "$delta9" ]; then delta_new_9=$(($old9 - $delta9)); else unset $old9 && unset $delta9; fi
if [ -n "$old10" ] && [ -n "$delta10" ]; then delta_new_10=$(($old10 - $delta10)); else unset $old10 && unset $delta10; fi
if [ -n "$old11" ] && [ -n "$delta11" ]; then delta_new_11=$(($old11 - $delta11)); else unset $old11 && unset $delta11; fi
if [ -n "$old12" ] && [ -n "$delta12" ]; then delta_new_12=$(($old12 - $delta12)); else unset $old12 && unset $delta12; fi
if [ -n "$old13" ] && [ -n "$delta13" ]; then delta_new_13=$(($old13 - $delta13)); else unset $old13 && unset $delta13; fi
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**